# Apex web service rest with auth0

Tags: apex, sales-cloud, auth, identity-provider

I want to give the possibility to our customers stored in salescloud to modify their information.

For that, I will develop an apex web service rest api.

Is it possible to use auth0 as identity provider?
Do i have to dig the custom auth plugin track?

The customer will have to access a site hosted on another domain. This site is a single page application.

Comment: You can use auth0 as identity provider.

Comment: Thanks @MIXDML
Must I use AuthProviderPluginClass for configure Auth0 ?
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Auth_AuthProviderPluginClass.htm#apex_class_Auth_AuthProviderPluginClass